# How to remove paint spot from clothes?

Tags: clothing, paint

My house was renovating a few days ago. I forgot that the gate of my house was recently painted. I passed by the gate and my shirt was ruined with wet paint which was not remove after washing. I tried my best to remove that spot but all in vain. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a gate, I assume oil-based paint was used. Soaking the affected spot in acetone for a while (or similar solvent) should desolve the paint (as far as I know acetone won't affect the cloth or the colours, but it is a good idea to do a test first).

If it is water-based (which I doubt), soaking it in hot/warm water for a while and then rubbing the cloth together should get rid of it.